# Create Unity Streamingassets via Microservice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing an App for my Hololens 2 and I want to use StreamingAssets so I dont have to rebuild/redeploy the app every time I change something with the Assets. Since I want to add lots of new Assets regularly, I need a way to create StreamingAssets programatically with the Unity Engine, but I struggle to find the Documentation to do so.

What I imagine is that I have a Linux Version of Unity running on a Server where I create a function that takes an Asset by name in the Assets folder and converts it into a StreamingAsset which then can be pulled from the hololens targeting that web resource.

I already have this bit of code that triggers the pipeline when there are prepared Assets:

```
public class CreateAssetBundles
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
    {
        string assetBundleDirectory = "Assets/StreamingAssets";
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(assetBundleDirectory);
        }
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(assetBundleDirectory, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget);
    }
}
```

I think if I can add the Asset(Bundles) to the pipeline programatically by name, I could create something similar to a microservice that offers the SteamingAssets as a web resource directly from the StreamingAssets Folder on the Server.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think your path `"Assets/StreamingAssets"` is simply wrong and not a valid system path. It's not a full system path which in Linux would start with `/` and it's also not a relative oath which in Linux would start with `./`.

Instead you should rather use [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) which returns the correct full system path to the [`StreamingAssets` folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) depending on the platform this code is executed on

```
var assetBundleDirectory = Application.streamingAssetsPath;
if (!Directory.Exists(assetBundleDirectory)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(assetBundleDirectory);
}
```

also note that in the case the directory is empty since you just newly created it I think it makes little sense to build an AssetBundle from it.

Comment: I think I might have expressed myself a bit confusing there. I want to create an assetbundle and then convert its contents into a StreamingAsset. This is just a hypothetical take how I think it should work but I just have too many insecurites about my assumptions being correct